# CQ5 page Inheritance

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I want to inherit the styles of Page A to its child page B. Can any one help me on this.

Ex.

Suppose I have added an xtype of selection Colors in the page properties dialog of page A. and the author selects any color( lets say Red) from the drop down it is changing the color but it is not applying to the child page of A.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem as though you are referring to a custom property, and making that an inherited property, correct?

I would take a look at the Inheritance section of [this page on CQ5 code samples](http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2012/06/basic-cq5-code-samples.html).  That will show you how you can read an inherited property from the page properties object.  You may also want to have a look at the [InheritanceValueMap javadocs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/inherit/InheritanceValueMap.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton shsteimer! it really helped me. Have a great day.